# How to make an Iteratable function (or however it's called)?

Tags: python

About a year ago my professor showed me a way of making iteratable functions with python but I cannot remember how to do it.

I remember it would be something like a for loop inside a function where there would be a break or return or continue keyword, something like this pseudocode:

```
def function():
    for i in range(10):
        print i
        break #or whatever the keyword was
```

And in the main program it would be written something like:

```
function() #prints 0
function() #prints 1
function() #prints 2
.
.
.
```

Could someone help me to remember, give me a sample code, a hint or anything at all about how to recreate this code?

Comment: Are you talking about a generator?

Comment: maybe, like I said, I don't remember the name, only part of the code/structure.

Comment: YES! `YIELD` RINGS THE BELL!

Comment: it was probaby something more like `def f(): yield from range(10); next(f)`. I guessed you were meaning a generator.

Comment: @AlexThornton: `yield from` was only added to Python 3.3 (e.g. fairly recent).

Comment: @AlexThornton That's strange, `yield` seems to work with my python compiler, which is working on python 2.7

Comment: @Yokhen: There is a significant difference between `yield` (which has been around for a *very* long time, optionally since 2.2 and fully built-in since 2.3) and `yield from` (only since 3.3).

Comment: @AlexThornton Oh! My apologies. I did not notice the "from"

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [`yield` expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions), which when used in a function produces a *generator function*:

```
def generator_function():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
```

A generator function, when called, produces an iterator:

```
for result in generator_function():
    print result
```

or you can use the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) on it to get the next value:

```
gen = generator_function()
first = next(gen)
second = next(gen)
```

Comment: I'm no expert in python, but did you mean `print result` instead of `print i`?

Answer (score 3):

Are you perhaps talking about a generator?

```
def function():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i # the yield keyword makes it a generator

generator_object = function()

next(generator_object)
# 0 
next(generator_object)
# 1
```